# Can we get the source code of Matlab Spline Toolbox

Tags: matlab, spline, matlab-guide

I want to develop something like the Matlab splinetool GUI. Can I get the source code of splinetool GUI, and make same changes to build up my work.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply open the file in the editor and look at (and modify) the callbacks:

```
edit splinetool.m
```

In there, you'll also find how the figure is constructed (line 4085 in R2012b).

Comment: I've found the splinetool.m file, but couldn't find the splinetool.fig file. Where can I find it? I'm using R2010a.

Comment: @bitcold: oh, it turns out that they create the GUI programmatically. It's in line 4085 and following in R2012b (maybe this hasn't changed since R2010a)

Comment: Oh, there are only 3980 lines in the file. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @bitcold: you're welcome. I found the lines when I looked for the `figure` command. Anyway, please consider accepting my answer if you consider it helpful.